# 301 redirect to remove trailing hyphen

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, pattern-matching, bulk

I have hundreds of duplicate pages due to a trailing - (hyphen) at the end of urls.

Now I can redirect each one separately and it works, but I'm looking for a bulk/pattern match redirect which will redirect these to save a lot of work.

http://example.co.uk/example/example-   301 redirect too  http://example.co.uk/example/example

I've tried to create one with query string redirects that I know work for questions marks, but   I'm having no luck.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Q.Sheets, that's saved me a lot of work and also taught me something in the process - I can see where I was going wrong when i was trying to write it myself.

Comment: I had trailing hyphens indexed on some urls which was causing duplicate content. your solution fixed it. thanks!